# jQuery slider code not working in browsers other than Firefox or Vivaldi

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

there is simple script to reveal and hide some elements on page. Problem is that it only works with Firefox and Vivaldi, from what i could test there are problems on recent Safari, IE11 and Chrome 50 (57 all just works fine).

Code is located within source code of sub page inside script tag. It looks like contents of `$(document).ready(function()` doesn't execute at all, there is no error of any kind. I have only write access to sub pages edit, jquery version that is reported to be running is 1.12.0.

Similar code that is also placed in  `$(document).ready(function()` located in script tag in page head section works just fine.

I was wondering if it is maybe because jquery version. In code of rest of page, on which I have not much access to, there are several calls to google cdn to load jquery, could I load different version of jquery not affecting other scripts that use older version of jquery?

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var slideDelay = 1600;

$(".offer_close").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".offer_content").slideUp(slideDelay);
});

$(".offer_title").click(function() {
    if ($(this).next(".offer_content").is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next(".offer_content").slideUp(slideDelay);
    } else {
        $(".offer_content").slideUp(slideDelay);
        var tmp = $(this).next(".offer_content");
        tmp.slideToggle(slideDelay, function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: tmp.offset().top - 300
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: AFAIK, `$(document).ready()` is thoroughly reliable in all browsers. If it's genuinely not firing in any particular browser, I would suspect that javascript is turned off in Settings - at least that's the first thing I would investigate.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I did excluded tjavascript turned off right away

Comment: Add this `<script>alert("working");</script>` to the bottom of your html page just inside `</body>` (not in a separate .js file).  If that doesn't give an alert on those browsers where your code isn't working, then js is disabled.

Comment: "simple javacript code" is so vague. You should really be more descriptive when writing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did saved page locally and started to look through bunch of other JavaScript code that is inside page but it is out of my reach as for edits.

One thing did stand out, in `$(document).ready()` located in header there was use of `URL` function that seem not to be standard part of Java Script and it did gave error which apparently broke down jQuery copmpletly,  but at the same time did not affected Java Script execution in general. I did reached to help desk and hopefully they will patch it up.